# fillers string needed to fill the text document generated

Tags: apex, class, string

Need to generate text files which contain data in multiples of 10. i can have 10 lines, 20 lines or 30.

Using this code below.

```
for(Integer i = 0 ; i < fillersToAdd ; i++ ) 
{
    achFileTrailerContent = achFileTrailerContent + '\r\n'+ rightPadString('', 94,'9'); 
}
```

Always getting 11 lines. can you tell me the issue.

Comment: Can you add a more complete code snippet? I think we need more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running your code and get 10 lines of text... perhaps the problem is that you're adding an "enter" before each line... and because you have an "enter" before the 1st line it looks like 11.

Try this:

```
List<String> strings = new List<String>();
for(Integer i = 0 ; i < fillersToAdd ; i++ ) 
{
    strings.add( rightPadString('', 94,'9') ); 
}

achFileTrailerContent = String.join(strings, '\r\n');
```

Comment: Siva, if this helped you, please mark it as accepted so others can benefit. :)